# Design Practice: code to create before deletion in deletion test case?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, design-patterns, testcase

I have written test case for deletion of entity. In test case I simply pick first record by select query and pass its id to deletion method. Entity I want to delete can have some child entities restricting it from deletion. So I suppose I should create a entity first in my deletion test case and destroy same then so that I don't face issues of child dependency.
Is it good practice to write code for creation of entity before deletion. Its kind of testing creation method before deletion method.Please suggest

**Edit:** 
I am working on Rail platform, so I have features like loading database with fixtures (not using currently, facing some error with same, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288142/rails-fixture-expects-table-name-to-be-prefixed-with-module-name-how-to-disable ). And yes I am using configuration to restore database state after test case run.

Comment: You didn't specify if you were using a DAL, so I'll sound off anyhow :)  You should use an abstract DAL for your database access, and write two sets of unit tests.  One set will be against your high level code that uses the DAL (and mock out the DAL - get rid of the DB).  The other set will be against the DAL itself (which requires a DB to be in place).  This way you can minimize the complexity of your test data/test setup logic, and minimize dependencies in your more complicated tests.

Answer (score 2):

In unit-testing, you usually perform some sort of set-up before you run your tests.

Many testing frameworks support this sort of operation. Normally you don't do it through external queries though; for instance, you could directly create an object with certain properties, instead of performing an externally-exposed `create` query.

Because you directly create the object in the first place, you are not testing your creation query code (unless the way you internally create objects is flawed, but if you are concerned about that, you can test it too), and your deletion code is the only thing being tested.

Comment: If you can lay down a set of known data all at once (such as restoring a DB, or wrapping all your tests in a single transaction that you roll back when you are done), that might also be a good option.  That way you don't have to perform any database operations during your tests except those that you are testing, so there is less that can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> In test case i simply pick first
>       record by select query

This is wrong. You should not execute queries during unit testing.

Test that I see can be:

1. Delete an existent;
2. Delete a non
   existent Entity;
3. Delete a child;
4. Delete a non existent child;

Comment: Deleting an existing object requires a query to determine which objects exist.  Your first test case would require that step.

Comment: that's what test doubles are for. it's a really bad idea to depend on an actual storage medium on-disk or in the network when all you want to test is that the code behaves correctly when an item does or does not exist

Answer (score 1):

If your unit testing framework allows test dependencies, i.e. run test X only if test Y passes and pass Y's return value as a parameter to X, you can get away with it. Here's how that would look in PHP:

```
function setUp() {
    $this->dao = new UserDao(...);
}

function testCreate() {
    $user = $this->dao->create('Bob');
    assertThat($user, notNullValue());
    // more assertions about the new user
    return $user->getId();
}

/**
 * @depends testCreate
 */
function testDelete($id) {
    assertThat($this->dao->delete($id), is(true));
}
```

PHPUnit will skip testDelete() if testCreate() fails. This is a good work-around if you cannot setup a standard test data set before each test run.

Comment: sound good, not sure is to good idea to call test case of create from delete again (i suppose that is what assert statement is doing in your code). Will see if it can be done on rails

Comment: @Maddy - The create test is run only once. If it succeeds, then the delete test is called and passed the return value from the create test. It doesn't change how many times a test is run, it just allows a failure in one test to block another test.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good practice to write code for creation of entity before deletion. Its kind of testing creation method before deletion method.Please suggest

Yes, it's good practice to create the entity whose deletion you are testing, so that the test does not depend on external state, and is repeatable independent of other tests.

This doesn't *test* creation, but *uses* creation in order to set up for testing deletion.

If you have multiple tests relying on the same data, the creation can be pulled out to a method that you call in each of your tests that needs that data.  Most test frameworks also have a mechanism for specifying `setup` methods that are run before each test, and you could put the creation there if the data is needed for all tests in a test class.